# highlighting words in java

Tags: java, swing, text, highlight

I wanted to highlight the words,for a specific **time** (just like in karaoke apps).
each word will have a specific time for highlighting.i am able to take timings,but getting no where .How to highlight a word for a perticular duration.searched alot on stackoverflow and google,but dead end.
and can i take help of java script or html??
please help me out.
here is a piece of code how i am taking timing:

```
millis mil=new millis();
if(true){

if(flag==1)
    flag=0;
else flag=1;
if(flag==0)
value=mil.done(flag,start);
start=value;
if(flag==1)
value=mil.done(flag,start);//function to calculate duration
}System.out.println("val:"+(value-3086610));
   // System.out.println("gyjghjghjghj"+(System.nanoTime()-start2));
    String s = textArea.getText();

    char[] words=s.toCharArray();


    for(i=last;words[i]!=' '&&words[i]!='\n';i++,last=i)
    {

    }
 try {//System.out.println(acount);
            hilit.addHighlight(first, last, painter);

        last++;   first=last;

        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(newh.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

this is how i am able to time each word.
thank you.

Comment: It is a desktop app or applet (java) or a web one (javascript)?

Comment: What kind of UI technology are you using? Swing? Android? Something HTML?

Comment: yup m using swings,applets. please help.

Comment: set the background/foreground of the text with a color using the timer for a specific period.

Comment: well tried that.insted of timer, i was using System.nanoTime();
and was highlightn till the nano secs are over.not much useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+1 to StanislavL answer.

Did a short example hope it helps.

Here I create my words and their timings:

```
int[] timings = {2000, 1000, 4000};
String[] words = new String[]{"Hello", "java", "whoooooh"};
```

After start button is clicked:

[image]

after 2000 miliseconds:

[image]

After 1000:

[image]

After 4000miliseconds:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter;

public class KaraokeTest {

    private int[] timings = {2000, 1000, 4000};
    private String[] words = new String[]{"Hello", "java", "whoooooh"};
    private DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter highlightPainter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.GREEN);
    private int count = 0;
    private boolean fisrTime = true;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextPane jtp;
    JButton startButton;

    public KaraokeTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        jtp = new JTextPane();

        for (String s : words) {
            String tmp = jtp.getText();
            if (tmp.equals("")) {
                jtp.setText(s);
            } else {
                jtp.setText(tmp + " " + s);
            }
        }

        startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                startKaraoke();
            }
        });

        frame.add(jtp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(startButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void startKaraoke() {
        if (fisrTime) {
            startButton.setEnabled(false);
            fisrTime = false;
        }
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Timer t = createAndStartTimer(timings[count], count);

                while (t.isRunning()) {//wait for timer to be done
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        count++;
                        if (count == timings.length) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Done");
                            startButton.setEnabled(true);
                            count = 0;
                        } else {
                            startKaraoke();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
    }

    private Timer createAndStartTimer(int delay, final int count) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int sp = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    sp += words[i].length() + 1;
                }
                try {
                    jtp.getHighlighter().addHighlight(sp, sp + words[count].length(), highlightPainter);
                } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        Timer t = new Timer(delay, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                jtp.getHighlighter().removeAllHighlights();
            }
        });
        t.setRepeats(false);
        t.start();
        return t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new KaraokeTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Fixed the above code to be able to highlight individual characters within the sentence for a specified amount of time:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter;

public class KaraokeTest {

    private int[] timings = {2000, 1000, 4000, 2000, 3000};//char timings
    private String[] words = {"H", "e", "l", "l", "o"};//each indiviaul word
    private String sentence = "Hello";//entire string for writing to JSCrollPane
    private DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter highlightPainter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.GREEN);
    private int count = 0;
    private boolean fisrTime = true;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextPane jtp;
    JButton startButton;

    public KaraokeTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        jtp = new JTextPane();

        jtp.setText(sentence);

        startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                startKaraoke();
            }
        });

        frame.add(jtp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(startButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void startKaraoke() {
        if (fisrTime) {
            startButton.setEnabled(false);
            fisrTime = false;
        }
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Timer t = createAndStartTimer(timings[count], count);

                while (t.isRunning()) {//wait for timer to be done
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        count++;
                        if (count == timings.length) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Done");
                            startButton.setEnabled(true);
                            count = 0;
                            fisrTime = true;
                        } else {
                            startKaraoke();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
    }

    private Timer createAndStartTimer(int delay, final int count) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int sp = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    sp += words[i].length();
                }
                try {
                    jtp.getHighlighter().addHighlight(sp, sp + words[count].length(), highlightPainter);
                } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Timer t = new Timer(delay, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                jtp.getHighlighter().removeAllHighlights();
            }
        });
        t.setRepeats(false);
        t.start();
        return t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new KaraokeTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the example. I would prefere do not writing code but let author write it but your example is really good!

Comment: hey pls dnt miss understand me.hope this will make you clear
i want something like this:
[link](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?start=150&num=10&hl=en&biw=1249&bih=595&tbm=isch&tbnid=PVh9qwi4dsc_jM:&imgrefurl=http://www.youtube.com/user/YouSingTheHits&docid=OcuUxGJsT46B7M&imgurl=http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/MEm2Shlwd4k/mqdefault.jpg&w=320&h=180&ei=KlSiUIj-EsvwrQfJtICADA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=489&vpy=305&dur=268&hovh=144&hovw=256&tx=179&ty=52&sig=117721448304548979275&page=7&tbnh=126&tbnw=235&ndsp=25&ved=1t:429,r:58,s:100,i:178)

Comment: @StanislavL I know its bad but I love coding and thank you :).

Comment: @joeyrohan I have already now shown how to do timings for a word, you can easily change this example to work for characters. Put in some effort you know?

Comment: Ok thanks:) will try best n come back to this post.but,this stuff i was able to do :/..
the timings are set at first,for wvery word.then the karaoke is played.so any karaoke can be played.so i dnt have to set timing for each char. evry time..dats problem.

Comment: @joeyrohan *,for wvery word.then the karaoke is played.so any karaoke can be played.so i dnt have to set timing for each char. evry time..dats problem* I dont get it, that's the hard part of the application is adding the timings for each word/character, not all songs will have the same timing per character or word, any karaoke that does not follow these rules is not karaoke application anymore

Comment: yup! that is y i am first aking user to press escape key,and set the time for that word(song is played in background).then i have to keep on highliten a perticular word(timed by user befor) till its time is not over.but user should be able to see its gettin hilited.
slowly...now how to get this???(same as in karaoke maker and player softwares...) am i clear now??please help.

Comment: @joeyrohan I see, well it still stands, simply make my example run for character and not words, than make the text and highlighting different colours and remove the call to `removeHighlights`

Comment: will try :)) thanks buddy
can i do this? i can divide the time as much as .length() of string>
and highlit the char in small small times till the total time of highlitin is achieved??

Comment: @joeyrohan I fixed the code for you. See my update. you can now highlight each letter in the sentence for a specific time

Comment: @DavidKroukamp thanks david.but i want to highlight a full word's .length()-2 and then last 2 digits.But that updated program is wonderful!! u r rely awsum man!!thanks loads!!god bless

Answer (score 4):

You can start from the link http://java-sl.com/blink.html

Add highlights to the JTextArea and le them blink for some time.

Comment: Change color based on timer so that it gives a blink effect. Right??

Comment: nice thought,but it will b nice if i can highlight them in accordance with the song..:))

Comment: not a blink effect...the word should be highlited for a given time... not blikn..
and dont have 2 use jtext area!! com'on!

Comment: It's the same. If you don't want a blink just add highlight for some time, then remove and add one more highlight. Just use Timer which adds and removes the highlihts

Comment: @StanislavL yeah, but can'n exactly match timings with the highliter.
for eg:- the word "alone" should be highlited 4 88888 nano sec.
then, it i shouold be able 2 see it getting highlited,ALone ..how to match dis stuff??

Comment: for each word you want to highligh create a timer and specify the desired time interval. The timer should have reference to the highlight. When action happened you stop the timer, remove the highlight and startd the same for the next fragment of text.

Comment: yup bro,i got that.but still point not cleard.
i am able to highlite the word for a time period.thats not a problm.
but wat u r telling is,i will highlit for a duation of time.but like in karaoke,i want to see it gettin highlitd.otherwise,it will highlit in no time.its complicated :(

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem.

Comment: have u seen karaoke? if yes,then exactly same thing i have to do.please help.