# Highlighting String in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, highlight, jtextarea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Highlighting few of the words of a text file opened in a frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481698/highlighting-few-of-the-words-of-a-text-file-opened-in-a-frame)

I am finding a string in `JTextArea` and once that string is found, I want to highlight that string with some color. I have been searching internet for finding a solution but couldn't find an answer.

How can I highlight a string in `JTextArea`?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437865/java-scroll-to-specific-text-inside-jtextarea/13438455#13438455) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448558/highlight-a-word-in-jeditorpane/13449000#13449000) then

Comment: `JTextArea` is for plain text (all one font, style & color).  for styled text use a `JEditorPane` or `JTextPane` instead.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12482171/1133011) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478892/highlighting-the-word-in-java/13480123#13480123) for some examples. +1 @MadProgrammer for his examples too :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Or you could cheat and use text selection :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer  Yes, I checked out your clever example a while ago.  +1

Comment: @MadProgrammer Awesome Man. Very clever solutions. Hats off :P

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use a [`Highlighter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Highlighter.html) for that. [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) Oracle tutorial should put you on the right track.

EDIT:

`entry.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);`: This attaches the current class as an event handler for the particular object. It is highly likely that you can do without this line of code.

`hilit.addHighlight(index, end, painter);`: This should highlight the text.

`entry.setBackground(entryBg);`: Sets the background to the given item.

I would recommend you copy the code written in the tutorial and start from there.

Comment: Thanks.

Can you please tell me what does the following lines of code doing:

entry.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);       

hilit.addHighlight(index, end, painter);              
textArea.setCaretPosition(end);                
entry.setBackground(entryBg);

Comment: @Alfred: I have modified my answer. I am afraid that not much can be done other than you having to gets your hands dirty :)