# working with Swing timer : creating mess

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, timer

Just want the color of the letters to change with a little pauses (pause may vary as per the time given for a word and length of the word).

The following code works fine for me.But I think I have created a mess with my logic.I can understand, but it should be easy for my team mates to understand.

[image]
[image]

Code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Reminder 
{
    static   JFrame frame;
    Toolkit toolkit;
    Timer timer;
    int point=0,temp=0,hil=0,point2=0;long time1=0,time2=0;
    static   StyledDocument doc;
    static   JTextPane textpane;
    String[] arr={"Tes"," hiiii"," what"," happpn"};
    int i=0;
    int[] a=new int[5];

    public Reminder() 
    {
        a[0]=1000;
        a[1]=900;
        a[2]=300;
        a[3]=1500;
        a[4]=1700;

        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) 
            {
                point =arr[i].length();
                temp=point+1;
                time1=System.currentTimeMillis();
                new Thread(new t1()).start();
            }
        };

        timer = new Timer(a[i], actionListener);
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
    }

    public  class t1 implements Runnable
    {     /* true idea to use current time is beacuse i want to check and make 
sure that the time taken since the timer started, and the present time should
not  exceed the time given in the array in any case*/   
        public void run() 
        {
            try
            {
                time2=System.currentTimeMillis();
                while(time2-time1<=a[i]-200){Thread.sleep((long) (a[i] / (arr[i].length() * 4)));
                if(hil<=temp-1)
                {
                    doc.setCharacterAttributes(point2,hil, textpane.getStyle("Red"), true);}
                    hil++;
                    time2=System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(point2,point+1, textpane.getStyle("Red"), true);
                point2+=point;hil=0;i++;
                timer.setDelay(a[i]);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void newcompo()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        doc = (StyledDocument) new DefaultStyledDocument();
        textpane = new JTextPane(doc);
        textpane.setText("Test hiiii what happpn");
        javax.swing.text.Style style = textpane.addStyle("Red", null);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.RED);
        panel.add(textpane);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
                                                                ,    InvocationTargetException 
    {
          SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() 
          {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                frame.setVisible(true);

                newcompo();
                Reminder aa=  new Reminder();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?How can I simplify?

**UPDATE FOR ERROR**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class KaraokeTest {

private int[] timingsArray = {1000, 900, 300, 1500};//word/letters timings
private String[] individualWordsToHighlight = {"Tes", " hiiii", " what", " happpn"};//each individual word/letters to highlight
private int count = 0;
private final JTextPane jtp = new JTextPane();
private final JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
private final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

public KaraokeTest() {
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    for (String s : individualWordsToHighlight) {
        String tmp = jtp.getText();
        jtp.setText(tmp + s);
    }
    jtp.setEditable(false);

    startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            startButton.setEnabled(false);
            count = 0;

            //create Arrays of individual letters and their timings
            final ArrayList<String> chars = new ArrayList<>();
            final ArrayList<Integer> charsTiming = new ArrayList<>();

            for (String s : individualWordsToHighlight) {
                for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                    chars.add(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
                }
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < timingsArray.length; x++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < individualWordsToHighlight[x].length(); i++) {
                    charsTiming.add(timingsArray[x] / individualWordsToHighlight[x].length());
                    System.out.println(timingsArray[x] / individualWordsToHighlight[x].length());
                }
            }

            new Timer(1, new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    if (count < charsTiming.size()) {
                        highlightNextWord();
                        //restart timer with new timings
                        ((Timer) ae.getSource()).setInitialDelay(charsTiming.get(count));
                        ((Timer) ae.getSource()).restart();
                    } else {//we are at the end of the array
                        reset();
                        ((Timer) ae.getSource()).stop();//stop the timer
                    }
                    count++;//increment counter
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });

    frame.add(jtp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(startButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void reset() {
    startButton.setEnabled(true);
    jtp.setText("");
    for (String s : individualWordsToHighlight) {
        String tmp = jtp.getText();
        jtp.setText(tmp + s);
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Done");
}

private void highlightNextWord() {
    //we still have words to highlight
    int sp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count + 1; i++) {//get count for number of letters in words (we add 1 because counter is only incrementd after this method is called)
        sp += 1;
    }
    //highlight words
    Style style = jtp.addStyle("RED", null);
    StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.RED);
    ((StyledDocument) jtp.getDocument()).setCharacterAttributes(0, sp, style, true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new KaraokeTest();
        }
    });
}
}
```

[image]

Gives me Exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - illegal start of type
    at KaraokeTest$1.actionPerformed(KaraokeTest.java:47)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6263)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6028)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4574)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2475)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: *"I have created a mess with my logic"*  That code indentation is definitely a mess.  Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: What's with starting a Thread when the Timer executes? The whole point of using the timer is to be executed within the context of the EDT at a set interval

Comment: Voted to close as off topic, as code is fully functional. *Any suggestions?How can I simplify?* I think this is better off at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for advice, intended my code.

Comment: @MadProgrammer when i did that colouring part in my swing timer,it freezes the program,thats why a new thread.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp its not only it.Please consider MadProgrammer's comment and my reply.This is a problem too

Comment: @joeyrohan perhaps true, decided to look at your question and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14296247/1133011) is what I came up with. Also your current code throws an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` due to your timing array being bigger than amount of words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, here is a cleaned up version of your code which should approximatively perform the same thing:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class Reminder {
    private static final String TEXT = "Test hiiii what happpn";
    private static final String[] WORDS = TEXT.split(" ");
    private JFrame frame;
    private Timer timer;
    private StyledDocument doc;
    private JTextPane textpane;
    private List<Integer> times = Arrays.asList(1000, 900, 300, 1500);

    private int stringIndex = 0;
    private int index = 0;

    public void startColoring() {
        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                doc.setCharacterAttributes(stringIndex, 1, textpane.getStyle("Red"), true);
                stringIndex++;
                try {
                    if (stringIndex >= doc.getLength() || doc.getText(stringIndex, 1).equals(" ")) {
                        index++;
                    }
                    if (index < times.size()) {
                        double delay = times.get(index).doubleValue();
                        timer.setDelay((int) (delay / WORDS[index].length()));
                    } else {
                        timer.stop();
                        System.err.println("Timer stopped");
                    }
                } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        timer = new Timer(times.get(index), actionListener);
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        doc = new DefaultStyledDocument();
        textpane = new JTextPane(doc);
        textpane.setText(TEXT);
        javax.swing.text.Style style = textpane.addStyle("Red", null);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.RED);
        panel.add(textpane);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Reminder reminder = new Reminder();
                reminder.initUI();
                reminder.startColoring();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

A few tricks to help others read and understand your code:

- Use coherent and appropriate indentation (I personnally try to stick to default Sun Java conventions)
- Follow the Java coding conventions (constants are in upper-case, class name starts with an upper-case, variables and methods start with a lower case, use camel case)
- Use meaningful variable and method names
- class member should be declared one by one (don't use `int i, j, k;` )
- Use a single instruction per line (avoid stuffs like `if(something) doSomething(); else {doSomethingElse1(); doSomethingElse2();}` on a single line)
- Avoid unnecessary usage of the `static` keyword (to the exception of constants)
- Try to avoid coupling your code so much (try to make the minimum assumptions on how the rest of the code performs)
- Add javadoc and comments in your code, this is always a good practice and it is of great help for you and others.

Comment: Nice, cool +1.But there is difference in highlighting the text.The mess is cause of that.It should highlight till the timer is not over,other words,the letters getting highlighted, should be visible,with some appropriate delay.

Comment: @joeyrohan Could you describe those differences?

Comment: Try to run my code and see.You will be able to make out after that.

Comment: @joeyrohan I see that your words don't get entirely coloured immediately but I can't find any logic behind that. It would be a lot easier if you describe what should happen. I saw that you put some sleep mechanism in your `Thread` but I don't understand what it should perform.

Comment: Well, it should highlight slowly, just like a karaoke..
the words have been timed, so should be highlighted within that time but as you can see in my code, not immediately.Just like karaoke thing.can you help?And about that sleep thing..it should sleep according to the word length and delay time given to that word..

Comment: @joeyrohan see my updated code example. You can truly see each character getting highlighted one by one and according to the word-delay divided by the length of the word.

Comment: @joeyrohan the idea is to provide the most fluid animation of the characters, so this means that we have to work character per character, one by one. (Hence we only perform increments of 1). The rest is pure algorithmic logic: 1) we change the style of the next character. 2) Next we check if the next character is a whitespace (in which case we go to the next word) 3) We check if there are still some words/times (if not, we stop the timer) 4) For each character of a word, a given time is provided ("time for word" divided by "word length"). That time is set as the next delay of the `Timer`.

Comment: @joeyrohan this algorithm has two flaws: 1) There can be many whitespaces between two words (so if there is more than one, the algorithm will fail) 2) We never check that the text is non-empty. Using a [`BreakIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html) will be a good solution (yet it requires some rework in the algorithm, but you should already have more of the insights)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet thanks alot!And indeed, BreakIterator will be a good solution.Thanks a million!For your efforts and everything.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet just one more thing, will this Eg work, when we have a `\n` but not a `" "` ?

Comment: @joeyrohan `doc.getText(stringIndex, 1).equals(" ")` makes the assumption that all words are separated by a " " (and the splitting of the text into words also makes that assumption). You could add very few basic tests so that you can skip any whitespaces and use a loop to skip multiple consecutive whitespaces (see also `Character.isWhitespace()`. The other solution (cleaner but a bit more complex to set up) is to use BreakIterator which will actually help you find word boundaries and skip whitespaces.

Answer (score 4):

Your main cause for concern is that you not doing the updates related to `JTextPane` on the `Event Dispatch Thread`.

For a situation like this, when you really wanted to update a certain thingy from another Thread, always use [EventQueue.invokeLater(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [EvenQueue.invokeAndWait()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29), which can `asynchronously (former)/synchronously (latter)` update your request on the EDT, though care must be taken, as `invokeAndWait()` might can lead to `deadlocks/run conditions` if not used in the right sense.

Here is your updated code, that might work for your expectations. Hope you can modify the code, as per your liking.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Gagandeep Bali
 * Date: 1/12/13
 * Time: 5:55 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class ColouringText
{
    private StyledDocument document;
    private JTextPane textPane;

    private String message;
    private String[] parts;

    private Timer timer;
    private int counter;
    private int start, end;
    private Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (counter < parts.length)
            {
                final int len = parts[counter++].length();
                try
                {
                    EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            document.setCharacterAttributes(
                                    start, len, textPane.getStyle("RED"), true);
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(len * 1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (InvocationTargetException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                start += (len + 1);
            }
        }
    };

    public ColouringText()
    {
        document = (StyledDocument) new DefaultStyledDocument();
        message = "Hello there... Joey Rohan. Had you ever thought about putting indentations before pasting your code.";
        parts = message.split(" ");
        counter = 0;
        start = 0;
        end = 6;
        System.out.println("Message Length : " + message.length());
    }

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Colouring Text Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        textPane = new JTextPane(document);
        textPane.setText(message);
        Style style = textPane.addStyle("RED", null);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.RED);

        contentPane.add(textPane);
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        thread.start();
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new ColouringText().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: COLOURINGTEXTEXAMPLE]

Comment: taunting through a window?+1 nice answer  :(

Comment: Hehe, pardon me for that, JUST KIDDING. But Please try to post `THE CODE` a bit nicely the next time.

Comment: have you tried out my code?You will note the difference in highlighting the text.

Comment: It's a new Theme I downloaded, just now for windows 7 from [here](http://elitebandofbrothers.deviantart.com/gallery/28710387#/d5kwb7s). Wanted to answer your question a long time back, but was occupied with these new themes

Answer (score 3):

Having been the one who answered your 2 previous questions on a similar task:

- [highlighting words in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360411/highlighting-words-in-java/13361657#13361657)
- [highlighting the word in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478892/highlighting-the-word-in-java/13480123#13480123)

and others not agreeing on my close vote, I decided to work on this a bit.

I have taken my [latest example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478892/highlighting-the-word-in-java/13480123#13480123) and edited to simplify where possible etc to make things more readable for you to understand, which in turn should help you understand how to go about simplifying your own.

I dont understand why you start a new thread to make words highlight slowly. Simply use my other examples and supply single letters rather than multiple letters and their timings to highlight, thus they will be highlighted individually. Or just make a method to do this work for you and iterate through those arrays as the letters and timings.

The below example uses an array of `integer`s which hold the *timings* for words to be highlighted. It also contains an array for each individual word/letters we would like to highlight:

```
private int[] timingsArray = {1000, 900, 300, 1500};//word/letters timings
private String[] individualWordsToHighlight = {"Tes", " hiiii", " what", " happpn"};//each individual word/letters to highlight
```

In our *start button* we have a method to convert the above to single timings/letters for each individual letter for a letter by letter highlight:

```
//create Arrays of individual letters and their timings
final ArrayList<String> chars = new ArrayList<>();
final ArrayList<Integer> charsTiming = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : individualWordsToHighlight) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        chars.add(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
    }
}

for (int x = 0; x < timingsArray.length; x++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < individualWordsToHighlight[x].length(); i++) {
        charsTiming.add(timingsArray[x] / individualWordsToHighlight[x].length());
        System.out.println(timingsArray[x] / individualWordsToHighlight[x].length());
    }
}
```

Next there is a single `Timer` which will be started when *start button* is pressed which will highlight words/letters and restart itself with a new delay each time until all words/letters have been highlighted:

```
new Timer(1, new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    if (count < charsTiming.size()) {
                        highlightNextWord();
                        //restart timer with new timings
                        ((Timer) ae.getSource()).setInitialDelay(charsTiming.get(count));
                        ((Timer) ae.getSource()).restart();
                    } else {//we are at the end of the array
                        reset();
                        ((Timer) ae.getSource()).stop();//stop the timer
                    }
                    count++;//increment counter
                }
            }).start();
```

Hope this helps.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class KaraokeTest {

    private int[] timingsArray = {1000, 900, 300, 1500};//word/letters timings
    private String[] individualWordsToHighlight = {"Tes", " hiiii", " what", " happpn"};//each individual word/letters to highlight
    private int count = 0;
    private final JTextPane jtp = new JTextPane();
    private final JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
    private final JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public KaraokeTest() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);

        for (String s : individualWordsToHighlight) {
            String tmp = jtp.getText();
            jtp.setText(tmp + s);
        }
        jtp.setEditable(false);

        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                startButton.setEnabled(false);
                count = 0;

                //create Arrays of individual letters and their timings
                final ArrayList<String> chars = new ArrayList<>();
                final ArrayList<Integer> charsTiming = new ArrayList<>();

                for (String s : individualWordsToHighlight) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                        chars.add(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
                        System.out.println(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i)));
                    }
                }

                for (int x = 0; x < timingsArray.length; x++) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < individualWordsToHighlight[x].length(); i++) {
                        charsTiming.add(timingsArray[x] / individualWordsToHighlight[x].length());
                        System.out.println(timingsArray[x] / individualWordsToHighlight[x].length());
                    }
                }

                new Timer(1, new AbstractAction() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        if (count < charsTiming.size()) {
                            highlightNextWord();
                            //restart timer with new timings
                            ((Timer) ae.getSource()).setInitialDelay(charsTiming.get(count));
                            ((Timer) ae.getSource()).restart();
                        } else {//we are at the end of the array
                            reset();
                            ((Timer) ae.getSource()).stop();//stop the timer
                        }
                        count++;//increment counter
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });

        frame.add(jtp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(startButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void reset() {
        startButton.setEnabled(true);
        jtp.setText("");
        for (String s : individualWordsToHighlight) {
            String tmp = jtp.getText();
            jtp.setText(tmp + s);
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Done");
    }

    private void highlightNextWord() {
        //we still have words to highlight
        int sp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count + 1; i++) {//get count for number of letters in words (we add 1 because counter is only incrementd after this method is called)
            sp += 1;
        }
        //highlight words
        Style style = jtp.addStyle("RED", null);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.RED);
        ((StyledDocument) jtp.getDocument()).setCharacterAttributes(0, sp, style, true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new KaraokeTest();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

In response to your edited question.

Again the code complies fine for me, which brings me to the conclusion our java Runtimes differ and might be causing a problem. Mine is:

> java version "1.7.0_10" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.7.0_10-b18) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)

**UPDATE 2:**

As per your comment on your java version:

> JDK 6, NetBeans 6.5.1

Have you tried:

```
final ArrayList<String> chars = new ArrayList<String>(); 
final ArrayList<Integer> charsTiming = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

note i dont use `<>` anymore as Java 6 does not support the *Diamond operator* it would have to have the data type included i.e `<Integer>`.

Comment: Pls. Don't divide individual letters of a word as String.Like that we can provide each letter a time.But try to make it out of a string of a word like "hello" not "h""e""l""l""o"

Comment: Seems to me, you got what the OP wanted. I am still confused about the mystery behind the idea regarding how to determine the delay, still working on it :-)

Comment: @GagandeepBali David's answer is nice but i will read a huge .txt file.Thats why i don't want them break into individual Strings.
See Polet's answer above.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp  `final ArrayList<String> chars = new ArrayList<>();
 final ArrayList<Integer> charsTiming = new ArrayList<>(); `
Gives me error: `illegal start of type `
I got the logic, equally good.Thanks :)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp I did that three times!

Comment: @DavidKroukamp  `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - illegal start of type
`

Comment: @DavidKroukamp i already tried that before, still no change.Also note the `List` used by Polet, worked just fine.What i think, list are weak datatype, may be something is causing problem.I don't know that something

Comment: @joeyrohan now im lost what java version you use?

Comment: @joeyrohan have you tried: 
                `final ArrayList<String> chars = new ArrayList<String>();
                final ArrayList<Integer> charsTiming = new ArrayList<Integer>();` not i dont use `<>` anymore as Java 6  does not support the Diamond operator it would have to have the data type included i.e <Integer>

Comment: @DavidKroukamp You were absolutely right.When i tried that code on my netbeans 7.0.1 the error was clear - `private ArrayList<String> chars = new ArrayList<>();(use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)`

Comment: @DavidKroukamp thanks for your valuable time and efforts.Have a nice day Ahead :)