# TimerTask runs just once

Tags: java, swing, timertask, javax.swing.timer

I have a task named `timer`:

```
timer.schedule(new task1(), 1000*minutes);
```

The task:

```
class task1 extends TimerTask {
        @Override

    public void run()
    {
            try {
                task();
            } catch (SAXException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(task1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(task1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(task1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(task1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(task1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    }
    public void task() throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException, URISyntaxException, InterruptedException {
        Pinner_xml t = new Pinner_xml();
        t.xml(frame.t1.getText());

        frame.output.append("task 1 \n");
        System.out.println("task 1 is running");
    }
}
```

`frame` is my frame name and `output` is a text box.
Why I run the task all is "task 1 is running" in the output dialog box in the Netbeans and the task runs only once.

Answer (score 9):

Use [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) for Swing, as everything is done on the EDT (by default) using Timer Class, which is the prerequisite, See [how to use Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). One more related example for [updating JButton on a Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10837751/1057230) and another for [working with Swing Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14294329/1057230) and [Scrolling Text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13098108/1057230)

Answer (score 5):

For repeated task execution use `Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)` or `scheduleAtFixedRate` methods

Answer (score 3):

Read documentation about [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) There is another overridden method to repeatedly execute a task, you are using method which executes only once You can use

> scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)

or

> schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)